# the second div gets included in the first div even though they are different and flex box not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<section class="third-part">
<div class="first">
<h2>PHILOSOPHY</h2>
<p>Following the ideas of the Old Academy, Zeno divided philosophy into three parts: logic (a wide subject including rhetoric, grammar, and the theories of perception and thought); physics (not just science, but the divine nature of the universe as well); and ethics, the end goal of which was to achieve eudaimonia through the right way of living according to Nature. 
    <br> <br>In his treatment of Logic, Zeno was influenced by Stilpo and the other Megarians. Zeno urged the need to lay down a basis for Logic because the wise person must know how to avoid deception, Cicero accused Zeno of being inferior to his into the comprehensible and the incomprehensible, permitting for free-will the power of assent (sinkatathesis/συνκατάθεσις) in distinguishing between sense impressions.
</p>
<div>
<div class="statue">
    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/sx21rnDB/Image-2-2x.png
        "class="statue" alt="statue of him">
</div>
```

---

I want a section in which there is heading and text on one side and a picture on the other side. So, for that I created a section in which there are two divs, first one has heading and paragraph and second one has the picture and then in the css I put display as flex. But it didn't work. When I inspected it, it shows that the second div is included in the first div only.

So, I have two questions

1. Why is the second div included in the first div?
2. How to make the flex box work?

Comment: Where is your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you are doing wrong is you are not closing the first div and that's the reason why you are getting second div inside the first.

Just close your  it will work fine.

```
<div class="first">
<h2>PHILOSOPHY</h2>
<p>Following the ideas of the Old Academy, Zeno divided philosophy into three parts: logic (a wide subject including rhetoric, grammar, and the theories of perception and thought); physics (not just science, but the divine nature of the universe as well); and ethics, the end goal of which was to achieve eudaimonia through the right way of living according to Nature. 
    <br> <br>In his treatment of Logic, Zeno was influenced by Stilpo and the other Megarians. Zeno urged the need to lay down a basis for Logic because the wise person must know how to avoid deception, Cicero accused Zeno of being inferior to his into the comprehensible and the incomprehensible, permitting for free-will the power of assent (sinkatathesis/συνκατάθεσις) in distinguishing between sense impressions.
</p>
<div>
```

to

```
<div class="first">
<h2>PHILOSOPHY</h2>
<p>Following the ideas of the Old Academy, Zeno divided philosophy into three parts: logic (a wide subject including rhetoric, grammar, and the theories of perception and thought); physics (not just science, but the divine nature of the universe as well); and ethics, the end goal of which was to achieve eudaimonia through the right way of living according to Nature. 
    <br> <br>In his treatment of Logic, Zeno was influenced by Stilpo and the other Megarians. Zeno urged the need to lay down a basis for Logic because the wise person must know how to avoid deception, Cicero accused Zeno of being inferior to his into the comprehensible and the incomprehensible, permitting for free-will the power of assent (sinkatathesis/συνκατάθεσις) in distinguishing between sense impressions.
</p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: yes that helped. I don't how I missed that. I checked it like three times! . But thank you so much. 

Cheers
Sagar